# Delete/Drop columns using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Oracle Timesten 11 DB and I have to drop a column from my application. I tried using SchemaUpdate in the beginning but it didn't work. Then I used SchemaExport's execute method to drop the column; Though the drop column was succesful, it ended up deleting all the records in the table. Also, I am using a .jar file as input to do create/delete/modify tables. Kindly help me fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective JDBC is the way to go if DDL operations are what you want to perform from your application. SchemaUpdate's purpose should be performing synchronization between your business model and database physical structure.

**EDIT**

Just now figured out that you probably updated your business model (entities) by removing field(s), and are wondering why it isn't reflected on your DB. SchemaUpdate will create new columns (and tables) but it will not drop those removed from your entities.

**EDIT2**

> Then I used SchemaExport's execute method to drop the column; Though
>   the drop column was succesful, it ended up deleting all the records in
>   the table.

It seems that you used schema export strategy that doesn't 'update', instead it drops existing tables and creates new ones when SessionFactory gets created (see Hibernate property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, most likely value was set to `create-drop`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the schema export strategy that I used was "update" and it didn't work then as well.

Comment: Also, the SchemaExport's execute method does a drop and a create in itself. Not sure if it is a bug with the existing SchemaExport class.

Comment: @Rohini: 'update' strategy would not drop any existing columns. Now you are probably using SchemaExport#execute(script, export, justDrop, justCreate). I never used it before, but justCreate = false would drop tables entirely to be re-created in later steps. I even looked into sources, and learned about interface RelationModel (javadoc:  "relational object which may be created using DDL"), it has #sqlDropString method. There're implementations for keys, tables, indexes. Obsolete columns can be dropped manually or using your custom JDBC-based utility when it's really required.

Comment: Thanks much. But the problem with the #sqlDropString approach (w.r.t my application) is, I do not know the column name to be deleted because the input from the user is a .jar file in which the field would be missing, and the .har gets updated accordingly. So how do I go about using sqlDropString way? any other suggestions?

Comment: I mentioned #sqlDropString just to point you to the result of my investigation, which proves there's no functionality out-of-the box to make Hibernate do smart decisions about which columns to be dropped. If 'drop columns' is a must have requirement, I would do it the following way: scan through Hibernate configuration (entity names) + retrieve DB metadata for tables referenced by those entities; and drop those columns that are not found in Hibernate entities. There're many pitfalls here, this is a hard task to accomplish! You should seek for a conceptually different resolution of problem.